# Free memory when deleting records in SQLite android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio

I have a question about SQLite records in android studio.

When a record is deleted, the memory is recovered or is there any way to free up the space that is occupied in the registry?

Thank :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to execute the `VACUUM;` command to free up space in your sqlite database.
By default, sqlite assigns the space of deleted rows to the 'free-page' and reuses the space when new rows are inserted.

Also see [this tutorial](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-vacuum/)

Not sure if that answered your question, because I do not understand why you speak of memory and registry. But in case you meant disk-space, this will help you.

Comment: Ok, Thank this respond my question , the reazon is becase I am workin with images and data in my database and I need to send this information to a api rest in case if this are not available

Comment: @JorgeOmarTovarMartínez nice, if the answer helped you can also upvote :)